# Capture standard output contents of one process from other process in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

```
    with ArPyUtils.StdoutInterceptor() as out1:
       config.enabled = True
       config.loggingEnabled = True
       # wait for supplicant to restart with a new pid
       Tac.waitFor( lambda: ( os.path.exists( pidfilePath ) and
                              os.path.getctime( pidfilePath ) > pidfileCreationTime ),
                              description='connectivity-monitor to come up again with pidfile' )
       assert ( open( pidfilePath ).read() != processPid )
       output = out1.contents()
       assert ( "Starting cloudtracer probe" in output )
```

Here I am trying to catch the contents of process from standard output but I am getting nothing i.e. output is empty. What I found out is beacause the contents which I am trying to capture are running as a seperate process. How to capture it's contents?

connectivity-monitor is the process whose contents I am trying to capture.I don't have any control over it, I am just checking for it's presence. How can I capture it's contents?

Comment: In short I want to capture stdout content of child process in parent process.

Comment: Is it an already running external process or a subprocess you have created with `Popen`?

Comment: @DeanFenster no, it is not created using binay, it starts by itself ... process is a binary running.